# How can I copy the exact used space and free space of a partition in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, disk-space, copy-paste

How can I copy the exact used space and free space of a partition somewhere in Windows Explorer?

I tried going to the partition's properties but the number of bytes cannot be copied:

[image]

Maybe this can be achieved somewhere else in Windows Explorer? I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Don't think you can get it from Explorer, but this bit of **PowerShell** will copy the values to the clipboard: `set-clipboard (Get-PSDrive c | select used, free)`. Caveat: the numbers don't exactly match the **Properties** dialog

Comment: ...and you could use the above as the basis for a context menu command.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just open the windows command prompt (win key + r) then type "cmd".Then use any of the following methods:

- Type "cd\" and then type "DIR", it will display the free size and you can mark and copy it.
- Type in command prompt "wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption"
- To check individual drives type "fsutil volume diskfree c:", you can replace "c" with the drive letter that you want to check.

dir is easier to remember but it wont work if a drive is empty.